# Problem manipulating local variable from FuncA to FuncB and return is not expected

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I created a function to update a local variable in `funcA` in `funcB`. However, when `funcB` returns, the local variable's value in `funcA` does not seem to correspond to what I've set in `funcB`.

See code snippet below:

```
typedef enum {

    A =0,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    MAX
} status_val;
int funcA(){
    
    status_val test = A;

    printf("before getvalue %d\n",test); //<-- this prints 0
    funcB((char*)&test);
    printf("value of test=%d\n", test); //PROBLEM: this prints a very large number. ex. 67108864 in my actual project
    
}

void funcB(char* val){
    
    *val = 10;
    printf("val inside getvalue=%d\n", *val); //<-- this prints 10
}
```

OUTPUT (EXPECTED):

```
before getvalue 0
val inside getvalue=10
value of test=10
```

OUTPUT (ACTUAL):

```
before getvalue 0
val inside getvalue=10
value of test=67108864
```

But in my actual code running in an embedded system, the value after `funcB` return in `funcA` seem to change to a very large number (67108864 ). I am very confused right now :(. It seemed to be a stack issue. If yes, can anyone point out some possible way to troubleshoot this? TIA.

Comment: Pop quiz: what is `sizeof(status_val)`, or `sizeof(test)`? Hint: according to the shown code, it's not 1, so you can pretty much figure out the rest of your problem by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you for your response, I printed out the size of both status_val and test. sizeof statusval=4 sizeof test=4

Comment: So, how do you expect to meaningfully set something that's `sizeof` of 4 through a `char *`, since `char`'s `sizeof` is 1? I trust that the problem is obvious to you, now?

Comment: strange same works on one of the online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/SJx15zzqv

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, i am not getting char but char *.

Comment: @csavvy yes, that's part of my confusion

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, why is the problem only occur with my power-pc project and not in other compilers?

Comment: The reason power-pc is different than an Intel based processor is probably integer byte ordering... Intel integers store least-significant-byte first, whereas power-pc IIRC store them most-significant-byte first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`funcB` is expecting a `char *`, but you're passing in a `status_val *`.  Enumerated types are typically implemented as type `int` so you you're using an incompatible pointer type.

Change `funcB` to accept the proper type:

```
void funcB(status_val *val){
```

Comment: In funcA, I perform a cast to char when calling funcB --> funcB((char*)&test) so they should be compatible

Comment: @cabrillosa They are **not**.  The cast is you lying to the compiler and saying they are.

Comment: I am currently compiling. But why is the problem only occur in my power-pc project and not in other compilers?

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as a result of writing through an invalid pointer type.  Inconsistency as a manifestation of that.

Comment: Guessing your power-pc compiler uses default big-endian byte order funcB manipulates/hacks the MSB. Hence you get the large value. With little-endian the LSB is patched.